# Django models JSONField filter

Tags: python, django

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не находит данные в БД таким запросом?

Models:

```
class anketa(models.Model):
    request_json = models.JSONField()
    get_json = models.JSONField()
    #timestamp = UnixDateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    timestamp = UnixDateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    operator = ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

БД (столбец request_json):

```
"{\"external_id\": \"43262\", \"external_meta\": {\"amount\": 35000, \"period\": 30, \"lastname\": \"\\u0418\\u0432\\u0430\\u043d\\u043e\\u0432\\u0430\", \"firstname\": \"\\u0410\\u043d\\u043d\\u0430\", \"middelname\": \"\\u0413\\u0435\\u043d\\u043d\\u0430\\u0434\\u0438\\u0435\\u0432\\u043d\\u0430\", \"phone\": \"79680934942\", \"birthdate\": \"10.10.1992\", \"city\": \"\\u041c\\u043e\\u0441\\u043a\\u0432\\u0430\"}, \"contacts\": {\"lastname\": \"\\u041f\\u0435\\u0442\\u0440\\u043e\\u0432\", \"firstname\": \"\\u0421\\u0435\\u0440\\u0433\\u0435\\u0439\", \"middelname\": \"\\u042e\\u0440\\u044c\\u0435\\u0432\\u0438\\u0447\", \"phone\": \"79002349595\", \"relation\": 1}}"
```

Запрос:

```
anketa.objects.filter(request_json__contains=[{'external_id': '43262'}]):
```

Comment: Уберите квадратные скобки `[]` возможно?

Comment: пробовал, не помогло